# Draw nodes in fixed position with coordinates in Networks python

Tags: python, coordinates, networkx

I am trying to draw nodes with the attributes 'name', 'latitude', and 'longitude'. I tried to draw it with the below code, but it returns different graph everytime. How to fix the position of the nodes?

```
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
for n, p in pos.items():
   G.node[n]['pos'] = p

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, font_size=8, node_size=5)
plt.show()
```

Below is the example of pos in line 3.

```
{'Baker Street': [51.522236, -0.15708], 'Bermondsey': [51.498129999999996, -0.0635], 'Blackhorse Road': [51.58698, -0.04104]}
```

Comment: Spring layout puts nodes in random positions.  So each call to spring layout will produce something different.  Take out the two times you use `pos=nx.spring_layout(G)`, and just go with `pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a `spring` layout, which is not the same as your target positions. That's why you are getting a different layout. In order to fix the positions of the nodes to the attribute `position` just do:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
for n, p in pos.items():
   G.nodes[n]['pos'] = p


nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, font_size=8, node_size=5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for comment! Yes I had not enough information about spring layout.

Answer (score 0):

First add all nodes to G, then create a dict using G.nodes() as keys.

```
self.pos = dict(zip(self.graph.nodes(), pos_list))
```

where *pos_list* is a list of tuples containing the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks to comment. It returns same random graph.